# YADCF for DataTables: Filter container could not be found

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I'm trying to implement [YADCF externally triggered column filter](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_source_externally_triggered.html), however I get this error in my console:

```
ERROR: Filter container could not be found, columnObj.filter_container_selector: #external_filter_container_0
ERROR: Filter container could not be found, columnObj.filter_container_selector: #external_filter_container_1
```

two times in a row.

My JS looks like this:

```
var myTable = $('#seller-offers-table').DataTable();
yadcf.init(myTable, [
  {
    column_number: 0,
    filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_0',
    filter_type: 'range_date'
  },
  {
    column_number: 1,
    filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_1',
    filter_type: "auto_complete",
    text_data_delimiter: ","
  }
],{   externally_triggered: true} );
```

My DataTable DOM part looks like this:

```
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'B>>" +
  "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
  "<'row'<'col-sm-5'l><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

My DataTable populates correctly, no errors, however I do not see filtering fields. What I'm doing wrong here, please? I use YADCF v.0.9.3

So far I haven't implemented any specific filter related DIV since I understand that is automatically done by `{ externally_triggered: true }`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ids that are specified in `filter_container_id` must be present in the html (its your responsibility to place them).

As to `externally_triggered`, when you set it to true you filters will invoke only when you manually will call `yadcf.exFilterExternallyTriggered(table_arg)`

please go over the docs and read each of the mentioned above features